# how to populate items in Jcombobox in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have designed a form in net beans which consists of a combo box. I want pre populated values in the combo box. I am getting these values in the form of arraylist of strings from a method. Now I am trying to add them in combo box. It is getting set but not visible. I am not getting what is the problem with that.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.digitate.agent.bp.ui;

import com.digitate.agent.bp.ingestor.translation.service.TranslationSpecificationProducer;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;

/**
 *
 * @author 125529
 */
public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame1
     */
    public MainFrame() {
        initComponents();
        //addTemplatesToComboBox();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        jToolBar1 = new javax.swing.JToolBar();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jSplitPane1 = new javax.swing.JSplitPane();
        jScrollPane3 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jList2 = new javax.swing.JList<>();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        translationName = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        mappingTable = new javax.swing.JTable();
        destinationTemplateCombo = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        sourceFileNameCombo = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        submitButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jToolBar1.setRollover(true);

        jButton1.setText("+");
        jButton1.setFocusable(false);
        jButton1.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jButton1.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jToolBar1.add(jButton1);

        jList2.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>() {
            String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
            public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
            public String getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
        });
        jList2.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 200));
        jList2.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 200));
        jScrollPane3.setViewportView(jList2);

        jSplitPane1.setLeftComponent(jScrollPane3);

        jLabel1.setText("Translation Name");

        translationName.setToolTipText("");

        jLabel4.setText("Source File");

        jLabel2.setText("Destination Template");

        jLabel5.setText("Mappings");

        mappingTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Destination Field", "Destination Type", "Path/Constant/Script"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] types = new Class [] {
                java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.String.class
            };
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                false, true, true
            };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex];
            }

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        mappingTable.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(mappingTable);
        mappingTable.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

        destinationTemplateCombo.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "\"abc\"", "\"xxxc\"", "\"abx\"" }));
        destinationTemplateCombo.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                destinationTemplateComboActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        sourceFileNameCombo.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));

        submitButton.setText("Submit");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 557, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(sourceFileNameCombo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 197, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 112, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(translationName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 319, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 122, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(destinationTemplateCombo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 197, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(245, 245, 245)
                        .addComponent(submitButton)))
                .addContainerGap(21, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(translationName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(sourceFileNameCombo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(8, 8, 8)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(destinationTemplateCombo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(58, 58, 58)
                .addComponent(jLabel5)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 178, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                .addComponent(submitButton)
                .addContainerGap(45, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jSplitPane1.setRightComponent(jPanel1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jToolBar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(532, 532, 532))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jSplitPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 619, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jToolBar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jSplitPane1)
                .addGap(6, 6, 6))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed

    private void destinationTemplateComboActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_destinationTemplateComboActionPerformed
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }//GEN-LAST:event_destinationTemplateComboActionPerformed

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
                MainFrame mainFrame = new MainFrame();
         //       mainFrame.addSourceFileToCombobox();
                mainFrame.addTemplatesToComboBox();
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                new MainFrame().setVisible(true);


            }
        });
    }


    //add Template List in destinationTemplateCombo
    public void addTemplatesToComboBox(){
        TranslationSpecificationProducer translationSpecificationProducer = new TranslationSpecificationProducer();
        List<String> templateLists = translationSpecificationProducer.getTemplates();
       // String[] items = (String[]) templateLists.toArray();
        DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
        for(String template: templateLists){
        model.addElement(template);
       }
        destinationTemplateCombo.setModel(model);
        setVisible(true);
        //System.out.println("Total Items"+destinationTemplateCombo.getItemCount());
         //add(destinationTemplateCombo);
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> destinationTemplateCombo;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JList<String> jList2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane3;
    private javax.swing.JSplitPane jSplitPane1;
    private javax.swing.JToolBar jToolBar1;
    private javax.swing.JTable mappingTable;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> sourceFileNameCombo;
    private javax.swing.JButton submitButton;
    private javax.swing.JTextField translationName;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you haven not populated your combobx

There are 3 approaches listed on [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)

first approach - After the call to initComponents() in the constructor add your code to build your model and call destinationTemplateComb.setModel(myModel) to set it. So the constructor would look something like:

```
public SomeClass() {
    initComponents();
    String [] myString = {"Item 1","Item 2","Item 3"};
     }
    destinationTemplateCombo(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(myString));
}
```

2nd approach:

destinationTemplateCombo.addItem(myString[0]);

3rd approach:

destinationTemplateCombo = new javax.swing.JComboBox(myString);

**First approach is much flexible then other**

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting these values in the form of arraylist of strings from a method.

Well there is no method in the API that will populate the data from an ArrayList to a combo box.

So you need to copy the data from the ArrayList to the combo box yourself using a simple loop. You can add the items to the combo box using the `addItem(...)` method of the `JComboBox`:

```
ArrayList<String> items = ...

JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>();

for (String item: items)
    // add the item to the combo box
```